# Recommendation System using SQL- Ecommerce Retail

Tags: sql, subquery, recommendation-engine

I am trying to implement a recommendation system for ecommerce retail. This is my first venture with SQL and that too designing a recommendation system from scratch. Can you all please guide from where I should start? Which modules of SQL i will be using exntensively and yes if there are any materials for me to go through. I know this is very vague but this is all I have for now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: stack overflow is not a consulting company rather problem solving, there are many different paths you can take and achieve the same result, it boils down to what your comfortable with, so I would say get your hands dirty and take it from there.

Comment: Yes I am totally aware of that and hence I am not asking specifics here. I am trying to find the direction here. For a newbie like me a little bit of direction or guidance helps as well. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I'll keep it short.

First of all, you need to go through your available data to decide which recommendation approach you would focus.

So, you also need to know basic approaches, like collaborative filtering, content based approaches, etc.

You will notice that, your data should be pre-processed, so don't limit yourself depending on SQL. You can move pre-processed data to whatever you want - which should be well supported by recommendation frameworks.